# Api JS code does not seem to react to an onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

I've been trying to get this JS code into one of my pages in Magento. Yet it does not let me run the code.

**Javascript:**

```
<script>

function emailSend() 
   {
       rrApiOnReady.push(function()    {    rrApi.setEmail($("#newsletter").val(););});
   }
</script>
```

`#newsletter` is the `id` of an `<input type="text">`

The button who needs to trigger the `emailSend`function:

```
<div class="actions">
   <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?>" class="button" onclick="emailSend()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe') ?></span></span></button>          
</div>
```

I've tried `$(document).ready(function() {});`
I've tried different methods to get this to work.
When using `alert("Hello World");` it's working fine. Anything wrong with the api's given code?

Is there anything wrong with the code?
The Chrome console says this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`
I've seen that it might be an extra `}`?
 Can't seem to find it... 
Any tips or tricks to get this to work?

Comment: try  type="button" insterd of  type="submit"

Comment: @SajithaNilan Hmm.. Alright I'll try this

Comment: @SajithaNilan Do you have any idea why `onclick="rrApiOnReady.push( function() { rrApi.setEmail( $('#newsletter').val(); ); });` is giving the `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ButtonID").click(function (event) {
         //stuff you want to do
    });
});
```